# Media Queries do not display on the phone correctly

Tags: html, css

A few days ago I finished editing my first site. Css displays correctly on desktop and mobile, but I notice that when I try to modify something in css to display on the browser on my phone, it does not take my settings. I keep in mind that the browser tools and the Blisk application get my settings and display the css codes correctly, but when I access the site on my phone, it does not change the setting.

I'll put two pictures down to see how it shows me on the Blisk app and how it shows me on my phone.

Blisk App :

[image: Blisk App]

Phone View :

[image: Phone View]

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
     header {
        height: 60px;

     }
    header img {
    display: none;
 }



nav ul {

    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;

}



nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 7px;

}


nav ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;

}
  .livada {
    width: 350px;
    height: 250px;

  }


.container {
     width: 300px;

}
.sectiune_text h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: font1;

 }
 .sectiune_text p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
 }


/* DESPRE */


 .sectiune_text_2 img {
    display: none;
            }


            .container2{
                width: 300px;
                margin:auto;
            }

    .sectiune_text_2 h2 {
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: font1;
        text-align: center;

    }


    .sectiune_text_2 p {

        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .fructe2 img{

        display: none;
    }

    .container1 {
        width: 300px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin: auto;   }
    .p2 h2 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: font1;
    }
    .p2 p {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .footer footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #222;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    margin-top: 30px;}

    .footer footer h1 {
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    /* GALERIE */

    .galerie {
        margin: 10px 10px;
    }

    .galerie img {
        transition: 1s;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 330px;

    }
    .galerie img:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }



    /* CONTACT */


        #map {
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
    margin: auto;

        }

 .adresa img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    float: left;

 }

.adresa h2 {
    float: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
}
 .adresa p {
    margin-left: 70px; 
    font-size: 20px;
    float: none;
    margin-top: 0px;

 }


 .telefon img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 90px;
    float: left;

 }
 .telefon h2 {
    float: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
}
 .telefon p {
    margin-left: 55px;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: none;
    margin-top: 0px;

    }
 .email img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 90px;
    float: left;}


    .email h2 {
    float: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
}
 .email p {
    margin-left: 65px;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: none;

 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Grande Bucovina - CONTACT</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

        }


        </style>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <body bgcolor="#ebebe0">
        <header>
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo site">

            <nav>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" ><i class="fa fa-home"></i> ACASĂ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="despre.html"><i class="fa fa-info"></i> DESPRE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="galerie.html"><i class="fa fa-image"></i>  GALERIE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html" style="font-weight: bold;"><i class="fa fa-envelope" ></i>  CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </header>

        <div id="map"></div>

        <script>

            function initMap() {
                var location = {lat:47.680870, lng:26.266649};
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    zoom: 4,
                    center: location
                });
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    map: map
                });
            }

        </script>
          <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDSw822pwdiQ09FK5h517ZrtTQa5mp3gx4&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
  <br><br><br><br>
        <div class="adresa">
            <img src="images/locatie.png" alt="locatie">
            <h2>Adresa :</h2>
            <br><br><br>
            <p>Jud. Suceava, cartier Burdujeni, strada Aleea Dumbrăvii, nr 33</p>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="telefon">
            <img src="images/telefon.png" alt="numar telefon">
            <h2>Telefon :</h2>
            <br><br><br>
            <p>Rotaru Sebastian - 0746547737</p>
        </div>
        <br><br>

        <div class="email">
            <img src="images/email.png" alt="email">
            <h2>Email : </h2>
            <br><br><br>
            <p>rotaruseba.80@gmail.com</p> 
        </div>
            <footer>

    <h1><u>COPYRIGHT &copy; S.C GRANDE BUCOVINA S.R.L</u></h1>

    </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

[This is my site](http://www.grandebucovina.ro)

Comment: what did you changed and didn't take effect ?

Comment: I modified " .email p {
margin-left : 65 px; } " and and nothing changes on my  phone. Anything I change on my phone does not get my settings.

Comment: your phone and almost any phone now its screen width is greater than the breakpoint you're making (max-width: 360) so it doesn't take effect as the width of your phone is > breakpoint

Comment: and how can I find out which is the exact size of the phone? I knew it was calculated for css: phone width / 3. For my phone it would be 1080/3 = 360px.

Comment: the most used breakpoints are: \@media all and (max-width: 991px) { ... }
\@media all and (max-width: 768px) { ... }
\@media all and (max-width: 480px) { ... } | **NOTE** the backslash before the @ sign is used to escape it from being used as marquing someone to see the comment.

Comment: Ok i will try this breakpoints